# Custom Prototype Cell with Parse - Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uilabel, custom-cell

I'm building an app in which I want to show a couple of rows of data in parse.

I want to have freedom when it comes to setting up the cell UI, therefore I followed [this tutorial](https://medium.com/swift-programming/how-to-display-parse-com-images-in-a-table-view-ios-swift-parse-com-f73dd68adb5e).

I have a class CustomCell to link my labels and UIImage

```
import Foundation
import UIKit
import ParseUI

class CustomCell:  PFTableViewCell {

@IBOutlet weak var nomePrato: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var precoPrato: UILabel!


@IBOutlet weak var imagemPrato: PFImageView!


}
```

And another class to set everything up

```
import UIKit
import Parse
import ParseUI

class TableViewControllerPratos2: PFQueryTableViewController {



// Initialise the PFQueryTable tableview
override init(style: UITableViewStyle, className: String!) {
    super.init(style: style, className: className)
}

required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    // Configure the PFQueryTableView
    self.parseClassName = "ProdutosVenda"
    self.textKey = "Nome" 
    self.pullToRefreshEnabled = true
    self.paginationEnabled = false

}


// Define the query that will provide the data for the table view
override func queryForTable() -> PFQuery {
    var query = PFQuery(className: "ProdutosVenda")
    return query
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath, object: PFObject?) -> PFTableViewCell {

    var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell") as! CustomCell!
    if cell == nil {
        cell = CustomCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Default, reuseIdentifier: "Cell")
    }

    // Extract values from the PFObject to display in the table cell
    if let nome = object?["Nome"] as? String {
        cell?.nomePrato.text = nome
    }
    if let preco = object?["Preco"] as? String {
        cell?.precoPrato.text = preco
    }

    // Display flag image
    var initialThumbnail = UIImage(named: "question")
    cell.imagemPrato.image = initialThumbnail
    if let thumbnail = object?["imagem1"] as? PFFile {
        cell.imagemPrato.file = thumbnail
        cell.imagemPrato.loadInBackground()
    }

    return cell
}
    }
```

The outcome: no error, just a blank outline of the cells with no elements and a spinning loading animation.

Comment: `var query = PFQuery(className: "ProdutosVenda")` has data?

Comment: `cellForRowAtIndexPath ` is called?

Comment: To be honest i don't know. When I use a cell with a standart style (basic for example) it works. I believe the problem lies in linking the CustomCell Call to this tableview.